# How to avoid multiple HTTP redirects

Tags: apache, redirect, http-headers

I was wondering if there was a way to avoid multiple HTTP redirects in the situation when content of the website is served only over https from example.com. Moreover for some long planing reasons the landing page is at htts://example.com/info/about.html

What it implies is there have to be following redirects:

- http -> https (via 301 header)
- www.examlpe.com -> example.com (via 301 header)
- example.com -> example.com/info/about.html

With such a setup whenever user types www.example.com he would be taken for a 3 redirects ride:
http://www.examlpe.com -> https://www.examlpe.com -> https://examlpe.com -> https://example.com/about/info.html

Is there a way to substantially minimize it, hopefully to one redirect? We are using amazon cloud, ssl terminates on load balancer, instances serve content via LAMP stack.